# Dynamic import in react using constant variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, import, importerror

### How should I use dynamic import in react native using variable ?

- I just wanna to use constant *`styleVersion`* variable of **`Version.js`** file.
- And import files accordingly to the *`styleVersion`* in the **`Text1.js`**

#### Version.js

```
export default styleVersion = 'v2';
```

#### Text1.js

```
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Version from './Version.js';

const loc = `../v1/TextStyle1.js`;
const loc2 = `../${styleVersion}/TextStyle1.js`;


import TextStyle1 from `${loc}`;

const Text1 = props => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={TextStyle1.text}>{styleVersion}</Text>
      <Text style={TextStyle1.text}>{loc}</Text>
      <Text style={TextStyle1.text}>{loc2}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Text1;
```

#### TextStyle1.js in v1 folder

```
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

export default styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    color: 'blue',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
});
```

#### TextStyle1.js in v2 folder

```
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

export default styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    color: 'red',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import)

```js
import Version from './Version.js';

import(`../${Version}/TextStyle1.js`)
  .then(styles => {
    console.log(styles);
  })
```

Comment: Not working in my case.